# How increase the right margin in matplotlib 3D scatter plot?

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot, bounding-box, scatter3d

I'm drawing a simple 3D scatter plot using matplotlib; however, the Z axes label moves outside the bounding box. I tried adjusting the size, using tight.layout, and many more option, but I wasn't able to move the plot in such a way that the Z axes label is visible. Here is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (7,7), dpi = 200)
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

xs = df_final_depth['Power']
ys = df_final_depth['Velocity']
z = df_final_depth['Predicted Depth (um)']
zs = df_final_depth['Ground Truth Depth (um)']

ax.scatter(xs, ys, z, s=70, label="Predicted Depth ($\mu$$m$)", marker='o')
ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, label="Ground Truth Depth ($\mu$$m$)", marker='^')

ax.set_xlabel("Power ($W$)")
ax.set_ylabel("Scanning Velocity ($mm/s$)",)
ax.set_zlabel("Depth ($\mu$$m$)")
#ax.tick_params()
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnQdb.png)

Please refer to the attached pictures. Tried tight.layout, changing the figure size and many other options. Can someone advise on solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add a padding to the `Z` *ticks* and *labels*.

So we need to use [`ZAxis.labelpad`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.ZAxis.labelpad) and [`Axes.tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) and adjust the following parameters :

> **labelpad**
> The distance between the axis label and the tick labels.
>
> **pad**
> Distance in points between tick and label.

Update/Add these two lines in/to your code and make sure the adjust the values (*if needed*) :

```
ax.set_zlabel("Depth ($\mu$$m$)", labelpad=-10) # Updated

ax.tick_params(axis="z", pad=-3) # (+) Added
```

Output :

[image]